# Can i use docker layers of pulled images for my locally build?

Tags: docker, docker-image

Ehi guys,
I've a question about how docker pull images locally and use cache's layers for local build.

In particular when i pull an image, Docker downloads all their layers. My question is: Can i use those layers for my locally build?

Comment: Are you talking about the intermediate layers created when doing a ```docker build```? Check out this page: https://medium.com/@jessgreb01/digging-into-docker-layers-c22f948ed612

Comment: Yes i 'm talking about intermediate layers. These layers are pulled from a registry when i execute a `docker pull`. Can i use (for example) one of these for my locally build if i launch the same instruction on the same context or Docker create a new intermediate layer?